# Windows 8 App Manifest: Image Assets Error

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

These images default VS images.But it doesn't work.

```
Error   4   Payload file 
'C:\Users\Mert\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Y\P\Assets\StoreLogo.scale-100.png' does not exist.    
Error   3   Payload file 
'C:\Users\Mert\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Y\P\Assets\SplashScreen.scale-100.png' does not exist. 
Error   2   Payload file 
'C:\Users\Mert\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Y\P\Assets\SmallLogo.targetsize-32.png' does not exist.    
Error   1   Payload file 
'C:\Users\Mert\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Y\P\Assets\SmallLogo.scale-100.png' does not exist.
```

[image]

[image]

I know question is incomprehensible but I don't find different way to explain.

Manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Identity Name="" Publisher="CN=Mert" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Y</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Mert</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.2.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.2.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="Y.App">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="Y" Logo="Assets\Logo.png" SmallLogo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="Y" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <DefaultTile ShowName="allLogos" />
        <SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Are all of the images in your Assets folder the default; that is the names are NOT decorated with .scale-xxx?  Once you have one with an explicit scale factor, the non-decorated one doesn't automatically get treated as a default (100). That could explain at least the first scenario.

Comment: @JimO'Neil I don't add scale images,I add only required images but:Error Payload file 'C:\Users\Mert\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Y\Y\Assets\StoreLogo.scale-100.png' does not exist. App is ok,I'll publish but this error annoying!

Comment: quite odd... do you get this on a File>New Project>Grid App as well?

Comment: By the way,I did not found solution and I create new project in VS.I transport code.Fortunately this project isn't so big...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also had this problem last day. I noticed that when I deleted an image from assert, it wont delete its occurrence from the **Solution explorer** in **Visual Studio**. Delete those files from solution explorer fixed the issue.
Cheers...!

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this myself.

It seems Visual Studio can't handle a trial-and-error approach for logos.

I got rid of it by manually editing the .csproj file and removing the missing assets from there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround by setting the Generate App Bundle setting to Never.